# Return Observable<boolean> from service method after two subscriptions resolve

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

I'm trying to setup a simple way to compare the current username with a profile's username within an Angular service.

Obviously the profile username and the user's username must resolve before I can compare them so how do I return a boolean observable so that I can subscribe to this comparison within components?

This is where I'm at:

```
public profileId = new Subject<string>; // Observable string source updated from a profile.component (when the URL displays the profile's username)
public profileId$ = this.profileId.asObservable();
public currentUser = this.principal.asObservable().distinctUntilChanged();

public isProfileOwner(): Observable<boolean> { // A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.
    this.currentUser.subscribe(user => {
            this.profileId$.subscribe(
                profile => {
                    console.log(profile + ' ' + user.username); // match!
                    if (profile === user.username) {
                        return Observable.of(true);
                    } else {
                        return Observable.of(false);
                    }
                }
            )
        })
}
```

This seems to be the way other SO answers explain to do it but I'm getting `[ts] A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.`

I'd like to subscribe to test within components.

```
this.authService.isProfileOwner().subscribe(
    data => {
        console.log(data); // should be boolean
    }
)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As noticed from other answer by @user184994, `forkJoin` won't work in this case. Instead you can use `combineLatest`, and then very similarily like @user184994 have otherwise implemented the service code:

```
isProfileOwner(): Observable<boolean> {
  return Observable.combineLatest(this.currentUser, this.profileId$)
    .map(results => {
       let user = results[0];
       let profile = results[1];
       return (user.username === profile)
    });
}
```

### [**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-om2uco?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: this is awesome, I've updated the question! I noticed that it doesn't work for me because my initial `profileId` is a `Subject` source. I need this to be a subject (I think) so that profile.component can update it with the actual profile username.  then becomes a stream with:  
  `profileId$ = this.profileId.asObservable();`

Comment: Well the difference between a Subject and a BehaviorSubject is basically that Subject requires `next` for subscription to fire. Not knowing your complete use case, but I don't see why you couldn't have it as an BehaviorSubject with initial value of `null` or something and then do a `null` check? Is that a possibility for you to do?

Comment: Thank you for patience, I was updating the BehaviorSubject wrong. Great answer to a complex question.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! user184994 did a good job as well, just needed some minor tweaks to make it work, so glad we got you a solution! :)

Answer (score 12):

This can be achieved through Subject

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

public isProfileOwner(): Observable<boolean> {
        var subject = new Subject<boolean>();

        this.currentUser.subscribe(user => {
                this.profileId$.subscribe(
                    profile => {
                        console.log(profile + ' ' + user.username); // match!
                        if (profile === user.username) {
                            subject.next(true);
                        } else {
                            subject.next(false);

                        }
                    }
                )
            })
            return subject.asObservable();
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

I would personally suggest using `forkJoin`, to wait for the observables, and flatMap to convert to an `Observable<boolean>`

```
return Observable.forkJoin(this.currentUser, this.profileId$).flatMap(
    results => {
        user = results[0];
        profile = results[1];
        return Observable.of(profile === user.username)
    }
);
```

Comment: great answer. Can explain how I should be subscribing to this boolean? (getting blank results)

Comment: What do you mean by "blank results"?

Comment: I've updated the question to show my subscribe code. logging the result shows nothing.

Comment: As in, the log message is never printed?

Comment: Yes, nothing is printed.

Comment: Nice. But I think you can use map() iso flatmap()?

Comment: @DavidBulté awesome. Care to write up an answer? Having trouble rounding third on this.

Comment: @user184994 turns out `forkJoin` only works on raw Observable types. `asObservable `, `Subject`, etc will not work.